How to change NetworkTimeout for DefaultAzureCredential
I'm trying to build a simple function application in Azure. The first step is to authenticate. The code, authentication part of it, works in cloud but does not work in Visual Studio 2022. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've been through several tutorials and they all say I should do the following
// Setup a listener to monitor logged events. It is needed to monitor actions by DefaultAzureCredential.
using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();

_logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

string userAssignedClientId = "REDACTED";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
                                                { 
                                                    ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId,
                                                    CredentialProcessTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                                                }
                                           );
var accessToken = credential.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" }));
String accessTokenString = accessToken.Token.ToString();

However after executing code on my machine in Visual Studio 2022 I get an exception. Here are the logs:
    [REDACTED] [Informational] Azure-Core: Request [REDACTED] GET http://REDACTED/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=REDACTED&client_id=REDACTED
    [REDACTED] x-ms-client-request-id:REDACTED
    [REDACTED] x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
    [REDACTED] User-Agent:azsdk-net-Identity/1.12.0 (.NET 8.0.5; Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631)
    [REDACTED] client assembly: Azure.Identity
    [REDACTED] [Informational] Azure-Core: Request [9REDACTED] exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:00:01. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.
    [REDACTED]  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
    [REDACTED]  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
    [REDACTED]    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    [REDACTED]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionWithTelemetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpConnectionPool pool, Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
    [REDACTED]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    [REDACTED]    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    [REDACTED]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
    [REDACTED]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---


Obviously, my next step is to modify ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout. But when I check for documentation. ClientOptions no longer has a Retry property. I should say it does, but it is not a mutable property. On top of that NetworkTimeout is no longer part of Retry. Here is the link to documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredentialoptions?view=azure-dotnet.
So my question is how do I authenticate in my dev environment, i.e. locally, with Visual Studio 2022?
I should also say I'm quite new to C#
Any help is appreciated.

Retry is directly available in DefaultAzureCredentialOptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredentialoptions?view=azure-dotnet#properties.

@GauravMantri It is a getter not a setter, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.clientoptions.retry?view=azure-dotnet#azure-core-clientoptions-retry, I can't set it.
public Azure.Core.RetryOptions Retry { get; }

@flashburn, Try using Retry = { NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300) }.

@flashburn, please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

To resolve the Network Timeout error, use Retry = { NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300) } in your code as mentioned in GitHub Issue.
I have created a Timer Trigger Azure function and used below code to generate access token.
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            string userAssignedClientId = "<Client_ID>";
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId,
                CredentialProcessTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                Retry = { NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300) }
            }
                                                       );
            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" });
            var accessToken = credential.GetToken(tokenRequestContext).Token;
            Console.WriteLine("Access Token is: " + accessToken.ToString());

Output:

Able to generate the Access token:


